# How to Decrease The Database Table Row Integer value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I want to decrease the value of stocks.  I am using a jbutton in java and using this code, but the problem is that it decreasing the all integer i want to decrease one stocks value.

If you have any questions please ask.

```
 try{
        Class.forName(Driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        String sql = "UPDATE goods SET stocks = stocks - '"+quantPOS.getText()+"'";

        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeUpdate();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Updated Succesfully");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a where clause to the SQL statement.

You will also need to convert the text in the text field to a number.

Also, use a PreparedStatement for your SQL. It will make writing the statement easier and is less likely to make SQL syntax mistakes:

```
int value = stocks - Integer.parseInt( quantPos.getText() );

String sql = "UPDATE Goods SET Stocks = ? WHERE ID = ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString( 1, value );
stmt.setString( 2, theIdHere );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Also, follow conventions when naming tables an columns in a database. These value should start with an upper case character.
    stmt.close();

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Your problem is that **it decreasing the all integer** but  you want to decrease **one stocks value**. This is because of your SQL statement.

```
UPDATE goods SET stocks = stocks - '"+quantPOS.getText()+"'
```

What above query does is that it will update the `stocks value` of all rows of `Goods table`. So, if you want to update only one stock value, you must use `WHERE clause` and specify that particular row id (using any unique column e.g. primary key column)

```
UPDATE goods SET stocks = stocks - '"+quantPOS.getText()+"' WHERE row_id=123
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a select button in that row and after selecting take all the values of that row in update panel in the particular textboxes and then update it using the update query sql.